# Posting HTML string as parameter to ASP.NET webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, web-services, post

I have a problem posting html tags from my angular app to my ASP.NET Webservice. I figured out i probably had to encode it. But even with encoding i get an internal server error 500. 
if i simply assign a value to the postcontent variable like postcontent="test" it posts perfectly to the webservice.

I have logged and alerted the  postcontent variable to see if it got encoded and it does.

So clearly the webservice doesnt recieve my html string and i wonder why. Below is my code
 $scope.CreatePost = function () {

```
        var graveId = $location.search()['gravid'];

        // get CKEDITOR value is structured like <p>placeholder</p>
        var getcontent = CKEDITOR.instances['postEditor'].getData(); 
        var postcontent = escape(getcontent);

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:51113/WebService.asmx/OpretPost',
            data: "username=" + userName + "&password=" + passWord + "&graveId=" + graveId + "&content=" + postcontent,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;  charset=utf-8' }  
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);

        });
    }
```

[WebMethod]

```
public void OpretPost(string username, string password, string graveId, string content)
{
    /*Context.Response.Write(content);
    var Customer = (from x in db._Users where x.UserPassword == password && x.UserName == username select x);
    if (Customer.Count() > 0)
    {
        _Post nypost = new _Post
        {
            FK_GraveId = int.Parse(graveId),
            FK_UserId = Customer.Single().UserId,
            PostContent = content,
            PostDate = DateTime.Now


        };
        db._Posts.InsertOnSubmit(nypost);
        db.SubmitChanges();

    }*/


}
```

Answer (score 0):

WebMethod has to return a value if you wish to `.then` on the POST request. Try changing void to string and then return a valid string, ex: "OK".

Comment: Nope didnt solve the problem. The function works fine if the postcontent variable doesnt contain html, but tried anyway with no luck. Thanks for the tip though